# Edit srcset and sizes attributes in Gutenberg image, cover and gallery - blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am looking for a way to adress the responsive srcset and sizes attributes on Gutenberg image blocks - like image, cover and gallery.

Usually one would do this with the 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes' filter, like:

```
function new_img_sizes( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
    if ( is_array( $size ) ) {
        $attr['sizes'] = $size[0] . 'px';
    } elseif ( $size == 'large') {
        $attr['sizes'] = '99999px';
    }
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'new_img_sizes', 25, 3 );
```

But Gutenberg blocks don't react to that. Is there any other way or a method to utilize this filter to change their srcset-behaviour?

Comment: For what its worth, my temporary fix uses Javascript to amend the attribute in a ugly way:

// srcset Sizes Gutenberg Gallery Fix
var hasGalleries = document.getElementsByClassName('wp-block-gallery');
if (hasGalleries.length > 0) {
  jQuery('.wp-block-gallery').each(function() {

      var images = jQuery('.blocks-gallery-item img', this);

      jQuery.each(images, function(n, image) {
          console.log(image);
          image.sizes = '(max-width: 767px) 600px, (max-width: 1000px) 1024px, 1400px';

      });
  });
}

Answer (score -1):

The code you showed in your question, is not how you do it correctly. Wordpress has a whole documentation [page about how to do it.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) You should do it like:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); // (cropped)
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is not what is intended here. Registering a new image size helps is something different than directly accessing the src-sets and corresponding widths.